# Get date of start/end of week

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

I'm need the `chrono::Date` of the first and last date of a week from the current year.

I have two issues,
first I'm unable to get `chrono` to parse the week of current year and second I'm unable to get the first/last date of the week. (There are a lot of solutions for other languages here, but not rust)

TLDR: I need a function like this:
`fn x(week: isize) -> (Date<Local>, Date<Local>)` with the tuple being (first day of week, last day of week).

Comment: What is “the week of current year”?

Comment: The first day of the week is either Monday or Sunday depending on your locale. Which one do you need?

Comment: "What is “the week of current year”?"

the number of how many weeks have passed since the start of the year :)

Comment: "The first day of the week is either Monday or Sunday depending on your locale. Which one do you need?" That has to depend on the local timezone. I need `chrono::Date` of that day

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, you can use something like this:

```rust
use chrono::{NaiveDate, Weekday, Datelike};

fn week_bounds(week: u32) -> (NaiveDate, NaiveDate) {
    let current_year = chrono::offset::Local::now().year();
    let mon = NaiveDate::from_isoywd(current_year, week, Weekday::Mon);
    let sun = NaiveDate::from_isoywd(current_year, week, Weekday::Sun);
    (mon, sun)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=164851f1118de5d28906ba3a653eda61)

That is assuming ISO8601 conventions (Monday as the first day and Sunday as the last, and ISO week numbering). It also returns `NaiveDate` instead of `Date<Local>`, which you could obtain using:

```
let date_time: DateTime<Local> = Local.from_local_datetime(&naive).unwrap();
```

if needed.

Answer (score 8):

you can try my crate https://crates.io/crates/now , it provide very convenient method to get beginning or end of week.

```rust
use now::DateTimeNow;

let now = Utc::now();
now.beginning_of_week();
```

edit:

for chrono you can use `datetime.iso_week().week()` to get iso week number. or you can use `now` via `datetime.week_of_year()` which is a simple wrapper for preview method.

Comment: Awesome utility crate! Thanks !